# What is the name for this type of operators: '+=', '-='

Tags: c++

Is there a specific name for this type of operators?

```
Sum += 1;
```

I've learned it in my first C++ class and used it a ton, but I never knew if there was a name for the short hand.

Comment: Google ->https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: Wow, it's literally just an operator?  My professor just called it "Short-Hand" and never mentioned anything else.  Googling "C++ short-hand" didn't yield anything remotely similar to what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there a specific name for this type of short?

Yes, it's called a ***compound assignment***<sup>1</sup> operator.

According to [Source3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment) the specific ones are called

- addition assignment
- subtraction assignment
- etc. ...

---

<sup>1)</sup> [Source1](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/), [Source2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators), [Source3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment)